# запуск Activity из BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-intent, broadcast-receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Intent intent1;
// тэг для логов
public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    intent1 = new Intent(context, WakeUp.class);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
    Log.e(TAG, "в Receiver");

}
```

}

Выдаёт ошибку: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: попробуйте    getAppliactionContext().startActivity(intent1);

Comment: @KirillStoianov, спасибо, сработало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `getAppliactionContext()` для доступа к контексту приложения